# Remove extension of url in iPhone

Tags: iphone, url, ios, nsstring

What's the best way to remove the extension of an url in iPhone?

I was using `[urlString stringByDeletingPathExtension]` but I just realized that it replaces `http://` with `http:/` for some unknown reason. Most likely this method is for file paths, not urls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the string operation reduces // to / (as a double slash does not make sense in a path), just use the URL counterpart, URLByDeletingPathExtension: on a NSURL object, which you create with [NSURL URLWithString:urlString].